# Cannot convert XXX to Varbit

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to insert user authentication token to the database. Token is first generated with the following code:

```
// Token is the type for authentication tokens
type Token struct {
    PlainText string    `json:"token"`
    UserID    int64     `json:"-"`
    Hash      []byte    `json:"-"`
    Expiry    time.Time `json:"expiry"`
    Scope     string    `json:"-"`
}

// GenerateToken generates a token that lasts for ttl, and returns it
func GenerateToken(userID int64, ttl time.Duration, scope string) (*Token, error) {
    token := &Token{
        UserID: userID,
        Expiry: time.Now().Add(ttl),
        Scope:  scope,
    }

    randomBytes := make([]byte, 16)
    _, err := rand.Read(randomBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    token.PlainText = base32.StdEncoding.WithPadding(base32.NoPadding).EncodeToString(randomBytes)
    hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(token.PlainText))
    token.Hash = hash[:]

    return token, nil
}
```

Afterwards, it should be inserted into the database by using this function:

```
// InsertToken inserts auth token into the database
func (m *postgresDBRepo) InsertToken(t *models.Token, u models.User) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*2)
    defer cancel()

    stmt := `insert into tokens (user_id, last_name, email, token_hash, created_at, updated_at)
                          values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)`

    _, err := m.DB.ExecContext(ctx, stmt,
        u.ID,
        u.LastName,
        u.Email,
        []byte(t.Hash),
        time.Now(),
        time.Now(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Here is my PostgreSQL database table:

```
create_table("tokens") {
  t.Column("id", "integer", {primary: true})
  t.Column("user_id", "integer", {"unsigned":true})
  t.Column("last_name", "string", {})
  t.Column("email", "string", {"unique": true})
  t.Column("token_hash", "varbit(255)", {})
}
```

When `InsertToken` tries to execute, I am getting following error message:

```
cannot convert [134 190 58 218 1 78 115 21 84 235 196 20 150 212 196 66 234 80 221 61 62 93 251 253 209 126 17 44 230 101 175 205] to Varbit
```

Where [134 190 58 218 1 78 115 21 84 235 196 20 150 212 196 66 234 80 221 61 62 93 251 253 209 126 17 44 230 101 175 205] represents my token HASH.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `varbit` is a bit string, zeroes and ones only. Perhaps you meant to use `bytea` compatible with Go's `[]byte`? But if you want to use varbit then **you** have to convert the bytes into bits, it is not the job of the driver or the db to do it for you.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.